# Changing title text color for ActionBar in AppCompatActivity theme

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I am looking to change title color in my action bar for which I am trying out as below:

I have added the following in my Styles.xml (v14)

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/AppTheme.DrawerArrowToggle</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/greenText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="background">@color/whiteText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.DrawerArrowToggle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_blackText</item>
    </style>
```

In my manifest: I using the same theme.

In my Activity Class: I changed the FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity

the OnCreate looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(getSupportActionBar().getDisplayOptions() | android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoforactionbar);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(imageView);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.register_new));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

        setContentView(R.layout.register_new);
    }
```

But the title text color doesn't change or I don't see the black up arrow too.
The text and arrow are white...

It is strange that the same works fine on another AppCompatActivity which has the navigation drawer too.

I get the result like this:

[image]

I have cut the logo part. Anyways, There should be black title and black arrow but doesn't show up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to paste this and change your colors in this XML with your own

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#cc0986ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0c84e8</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fdfff2</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#ff0043c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ffcb6345</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I used your theme and changed the primary color to white and windowbackground, textcolor : to black but still the color is not getting changed. It is still full white.. no black text or arrow.

Comment: You can use only opaque colors, I think. My color codes working in your app?

Comment: Yep your color code is working. I am trying it on Galaxy Nexus 4.3

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is the only answer that helped me to change the background color of my action bar.

Comment: For reference, here's an in-depth explanation: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette

Answer (score 0):

Juat add bellow lines into your styles.xml

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">your status bar background color</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/tool bar background color</item> 
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">tool bar text color</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">tool bar text color</item>
```